# Zend framework setup over local network

Tags: apache, zend-framework

I have zend framework setup and running on my desktop in my office which works fine,  however when trying to access the project I am working on I have to use the ip address of the computer in my office which works fine until I need to add a route like /index/list to the url in my browser.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: If you have figured it out, please post the soltion as an answer to your question, then accept it when you can. That way the question will be marked as answered and others with the same problem may find your answer useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The routes work due to magic in the .htaccess file. First make sure you have that file in your public directory (the same directory as index.php) and check it can be seen by Apache (check Apache error log for any complaints about it).

It may be that .htaccess processing is not allowed. In the Apache config for your virtual host look for something like this:

```
<Directory /path/to/public>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

It is the `AllowOverride All` line that allows .htaccess processing. (It allows other stuff too; read the Apache manual if you want to fully understand it.)

Comment: Figured it out, i just need to update the hosts file on the computer trying to access the server over lane with the following:

[ip of server] [alias of site on server] [alias you would like to use to access site]